# Flutter Row: Dynamic Height & Vertical Stretch

Tags: image, dynamic, flutter, expand

I have a `ListView` item that has a dynamic height, affected by the text content. This is a simple `Column` with two text widgets.

When wrapping the `Column` in a `Row` and adding an `Image`, I want the image to expand vertically (but fixed width) to match the automatic height of the text.

However, I cannot use `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` on the `Row` as it requires a fixed height.

How can I have my image, expand/shrink based on the text content beside it?

Comment: can u post your code please what you have currently

Comment: wrap your  row with FittedBox. Check it out: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `Stack` will automatically wrap unpositioned children. You can use this to your advantage:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Container(color: Colors.orange), // replace with your image
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(116, 16, 16, 16),
                  child: Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which would be the way to do the same trick with two `Text` widgets, one at each side of the orange `Container`?